# Plot vertical arrows for my points

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to figure out a way to add a vertical arrow pointing up for each of my data points. I have scatter plot and code below. I need the vertical arrows to start from the points going upwards to a length of about 0.2 in th graph scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
a1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

simbh = np.array([5.3,  5.3,  5.5,  5.6,  5.6,  5.8,  5.9,  6.0,   6.2,  6.3,  6.3])
simstel =np.array([10.02, 10.08, 9.64, 9.53, 9.78, 9.65, 10.05, 10.09, 10.08, 10.22, 10.42])
sca2=a1.scatter(simstel, simbh )
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `quiver` in addition to all of the other answers.  (`quiver` is especially useful if you ever want the arrows to go in different directions.) I'm guessing that you want to indicate that your values are a lower bound, so one of the other methods is probably better in this exact case, but `quiver` is useful to know about, regardless.

Comment: @JoeKington `errorbar` will actually do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other approaches presented are great. I'm going for the hackiest award today:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

simbh = np.array([5.3,  5.3,  5.5,  5.6,  5.6,  5.8,  5.9,  6.0,   6.2,  6.3,  6.3])
simstel = np.array([10.02, 10.08, 9.64, 9.53, 9.78, 9.65, 10.05, 10.09, 10.08, 10.22, 10.42])
sca2 = ax.scatter(simstel, simbh)
for x, y in zip(simstel, simbh):
    ax.annotate('', xy=(x, y), xytext=(0, 25), textcoords='offset points', 
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<|-"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is bit hacky, adjust `arrow_offset` and `arrow_size` until the figure looks right.[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
a1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

simbh = np.array([5.3,  5.3,  5.5,  5.6,  5.6,  5.8,  5.9,  6.0,   6.2,  6.3,  6.3])
simstel =np.array([10.02, 10.08, 9.64, 9.53, 9.78, 9.65, 10.05, 10.09, 10.08, 10.22, 10.42])
sca2=a1.scatter(simstel, simbh, c='w' )
arrow_offset = 0.08
arrow_size = 500
sca2=a1.scatter(simstel, simbh + arrow_offset, 
                marker=r'$\uparrow$', s=arrow_size)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not super elegant, but it does the trick

to get the arrows start at the data point and go up 0.2 units:

```
for x,y in zip(simstel,simbh):
    plt.arrow(x,y,0,0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible  for  the vertical arrows to start from the points going upwards to a length of about 0.2 in th graph scale?

Comment: didn't read the question properly apparently. Corrected answer accordingly

Comment: @DizietAsahi may I suggest removing the first part of your answer? The second response is so concise I think it deserves to be front-and-center.

Comment: removed first part of my answer that did not fulfil the OP's instructions

Answer (score 3):

This can be done directly

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# set up figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# make synthetic data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
y = np.random.rand(15)
yerr = np.ones_like(x) * .2


# if you are using 1.3.1 or older you might need to use uplims to work
# around a bug, see below

ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, lolims=True, ls='none', marker='o')

# adjust axis limits
ax.margins(.1)  # margins makes the markers not overlap with the edges
```

[image: demo image]

There was some strangeness in how these arrows are implemented where the semantics changed so that 'lolims' means 'the data point is the lower limit' and 'uplims' means 'the data point is the maximum value'.

See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2452

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that was an option!

Comment: Nor did I until that PR/bug report came through