# Writing an extra notation (caption) on a graph using Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, caption

I was wondering, if there is a way to include an extra caption on a graph for extra emphasis on a point on a graph.
Something along the way of below graphs:
[image]

Before:

After:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25023388/2454357).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'annotations'.  Here is the [pertinent documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/annotations.html) with examples.